# How to determine what user action triggered a JDialog resize event?

Tags: java, resize, awt, event-listener

I have added a `ComponentAdapter` as `ComponentListener` to my `JDialog`, and I want to implement `componentResized(ComponentEvent e)`.
The goal is to maintain the `JDialog`'s ratio, and for my calculation of how to resize it according to the user's action, I would like to know if the user dragged the window's **side edge**, the window's **top/bottom edge**, or one of the window's **corners**.

Is there a way to retrieve that information from the `ComponentEvent`?

Comment: what do you mean by "maintain the JDialog's rate"?  The word 'rate' is confusing in this context.  Overall you appear to be trying to do something that the UI library/framework is not set up for, but you might be able to achieve an overall goal another way.  So I'm looking for more info on the overall goal.

Comment: The JDialog contains an image. I want to allow the user to resize the window, but keep the size rate of the image. hence I need to recalculate the size of the image and window according to the user action (if the user increases the width, the size should increase accordingly, etc.). I guess I can achieve the same goal by saving the previous size and compare it to the new size... But I'm still interested in answer for the original answer. I understand your answer is it's impossible.

Comment: I would not say "impossible", but I did mean to say it is uncommon enough to be "unusual" with the evidence that the UI does not provide for it. Without delving into it, I would have thought it would be enough to get a resize event, get the current dialog height/width, determine the maximum height/width of your image that will fit there with the correct ratio (which is what I now think you mean by "rate", and redraw. You don't need the previous information, unless it's to eliminate redrawing if the size is identical, nor which dimension(s) changed.

Comment: Sorry, I did mean ratio. My bad... Anyway, if I get it right, what you suggest would not be enough. If, for example, I get the current dimensions (40,40) where the original image dimensions are (300,400), I can never know if the user tried to enlarge the window, and I should maintain the "larger" dimension and fix the other one (hence the new size is (40,53)) or the other way (which gives (30,40)). Keeping the previous size in memory lets me decide what is the user's intention and act accordingly.

Comment: @Elist: Go for the larger dimension ((40, 53) in your example) unless the dimension is larger than the display.

Comment: It's wrong to go for the larger dimension, as I made clear in the example. If I do, when the user tries to reduce the size by dragging only one dimension, he will be "blocked" and get back to the same size he had before (which is, in my opinion, very much not user friendly...)

Comment: But you ought to be able to calculate quickly whether to use 40,53 or 30,40; calculate scaling to each of the dimensions, and use the one that will fit in the space. This is what you would have to do anyway if the user had changed both dimensions at the same time.  I don't think you need the original size, only the desired ratio.

Comment: "use the one that will fit in the space" again means to always choose the smaller alternative, which won't be right when the user is enlarging one dimension. When both dimensions are changed, I can use the one that have changed more (which I am in fact doing in my code now), or make some kind of average. I assume that when the user changed only one dimension - that is exactly the size he wants it to be, but when he changes both at once, he might wanted it to be at "around this size".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know the answer for my original question (is ther a way to tell the source of the `ComponentEvent`), so I just store the previous dimensions, and calculate the new size.
If it helps anyone, this is the code I am using. enjoy:

```
public class ResizableImageView extends JDialog {
    BufferedImage img;
    Dimension OriginalImgSize;
    double imageRatio;
    JPanel jp;
    JLabel label;
    Dimension previousSize;

    public ResizableImageView(BufferedImage img) {

        ...

        setResizable(true);
        this.img = img;
        OriginalImgSize = new Dimension(img.getWidth(), img.getHeight());
        imageRatio = (double)img.getWidth() / (double)img.getHeight();

        label = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(img));
        label.setMinimumSize(OriginalImgSize);
        jp = new JPanel();
        jp.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(0, 0, 0, 0));
        jp.add(label);
        setContentPane(jp);
        pack();
        previousSize = getSize();

        addComponentListener(new ComponentAdapter() {
            private boolean allreadyResized = true;

            private void resize(Image img) {
                ImageIcon ico = new ImageIcon(img);
                label = new JLabel(ico);
                label.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(0, 0, 0, 0));
                label.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(img.getWidth(null), img.getHeight(null)));
                jp = new JPanel();
                jp.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(0, 0, 0, 0));
                jp.add(label);
                setContentPane(jp);
                allreadyResized = true;
                pack();
                previousSize = getSize();
            }

            @Override
            public void componentResized(ComponentEvent e) {
                if (allreadyResized) {
                    allreadyResized  = false;
                    return;
                }
                double xChange = (double) Math.abs(getSize().width - previousSize.width);
                double yChange = (double) Math.abs(getSize().height - previousSize.height);
                if (xChange == 0 && yChange == 0) return; 
                int height = getSize().height - getInsets().bottom - getInsets().top;
                int width = getSize().width - getInsets().left - getInsets().right;

                if (height > OriginalImgSize.height 
                        || width > OriginalImgSize.width) {
                    resize(img);
                    return;
                }
                if (yChange == 0 || xChange/yChange > imageRatio) {
                    resize(img.getScaledInstance(width, -1, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH));
                    return;
                } else {
                    resize(img.getScaledInstance(-1, height, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH));
                    return;
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```